# mPDF SetSourceFile - import PDF from temporary storage

Tags: php, mpdf, php-7.2

I'm trying import PDF file with mPDF.
PDF file is sent from other service, and my initial idea was to use [wrappers](https://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php). (preferably `php://memory`).

What errors I get:

`Warning: filesize(): stat failed for php://memory in /var/www/scrm/modules/AOS_PDF_Templates/PDF_Lib/mpdfi/pdf_parser.php on line 181`

`mPDF error: Cannot open php://memory !` (this one is printed to browser BTW)

I have PDF checked:

- displayed in browser
- saved to file, and imported from it

Both work, so PDF is not an issue.

I have checked contents of `php://memory`, they are valid as well.
Here is example code:

```
//part of the code, $content is defined earlier (.pdf file content)
$memoryFile = 'php://memory';
$handle = fopen($memoryFile,'r+');
fwrite($handle,$content);
rewind($handle);

/* dump it to string, just to be sure, part of how i was checking that pdf got saved to $memoryFile
   even with this part removed still doesn't work, so no file issue here
$str=  fread($handle,strlen($content)); //str gets filled with expected data
rewind($handle); //rewind for use by mPDF
*/

$pdf = new mPDF;
$pdf->SetImportUse();
$pagecount = $pdf->SetSourceFile($memoryFile);
```

Solutions I have in mind:

- save to regular temp file (I don't want to have to do this)
- is there a way for mPDF to import file from string? (Google yielded no results for me)

OS: Ubuntu 18.04 WSL, PHP version 7.2.31, mPDF version 5.7.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrade your mPDF version at least to 8.0.0.

Since version 8, mPDF uses updated underlying library FPDI 2 that supports importing files from `php://memory` or any stream, generally.

Comment: I was having an issue where the imported PDF was blank. no error message, it just failed without warning. after I re-installed mPDF v8.0.4, for PHP 7.4, the problem was resolved. I used composer within a VM, then copied the associated mPDF software libraries to my debian server, so that I did not have to install composer in a production environment.